# How to call javascript alert in a typescript component

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to call a custom javascript alert in typescript. The problem is that I can't use "this" keyword in javascript and typescript code does not wait for javascript function to finish.

What I am saying is:

```
declare var $: any;
declare var swal: any;

...


    delete(id: number) {

        var toDeleteOrNot: boolean = false;

        swal({
            title: "Are you sure?",
            text: "You will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
            type: "warning",
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
            confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
            cancelButtonText: "No, cancel plx!",
            closeOnConfirm: false,
            closeOnCancel: false
        }, function (isConfirm: boolean) {
            if (isConfirm) {
                toDeleteOrNot = true;
                swal("Deleted!", "Your imaginary file has been deleted.", "success");
            } else {
                swal("Cancelled", "Your imaginary file is safe :)", "error");
            }
            });

        if (toDeleteOrNot) {
            this.getagentiiService.deleteAgentie(id).subscribe(x => {
                this.populateAgentii();
            });
        }
    }
```

The function(swal) and the "if" are called at the same time. Var toDeleteOrNot in if maintains its initialization value(in this case it is false). I can't move the "if" inside the javascript because it gives

```
'this' implicitly has type any because it does not have a type annotation
```

How can I use this custom javascript function inside typescript?

Comment: Typescript is a superset of Javascript. This means that any valid JS file is also a valid TS file.

Comment: Ok...and how can I solve my problem with this?

Comment: Looks like you're new with the concept of asynchronism :) The `swal` function is async, so you have to wait for its callback to execute so `toDeleteOrNot` has a value.

Comment: @JeremyThille it's not asynchronous. Looks like he uses `sweetalert` and the function passed to the configuration is an event handler fired after the button click.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer out of curiosity, the OP clearly said "typescript component", so it belongs to `angular` tag, why `angularjs` then? or am I missing something ?

Comment: If it's actually about Angular 2,4,5, then the `angular` tag is right, it didn't look like Angular 2 to me. Perhaps even both the `angular` and `angularjs` tag are redundant for this question. I don't know if TS can be used with AngularJS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `function` keyword which is not allowing you to use `this`. Use the arrow function notation i.e. `( ) =>` and change your code to following to use `this` inside:

```
swal({
    //......
}, (isConfirm: boolean) => {
    if (isConfirm) {
        toDeleteOrNot = true;
        swal("Deleted!", "Your imaginary file has been deleted.", "success");
    } else {
        swal("Cancelled", "Your imaginary file is safe :)", "error");
    }

    if (toDeleteOrNot) {
        this.getagentiiService.deleteAgentie(id).subscribe(x => {
            this.populateAgentii();
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thabk you Faisal! It worked! I have too few points to be able to mark it as an answer...

Comment: you can accept the answer by clicking the checkmark, does not depend on the points you have. Or am I wrong here? \o/ read here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Comment: @Faisal He still has to wait a couple of minutes before he can accept the answer. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250132/why-cant-i-accept-an-answer-in-the-first-15-minutes-after-asking-the-question